# How to check if WiFi exists?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

How can i check if the WiFi name i have entered exists in the area i m in?

The idea is to get the names from the WiFi networks , compare them to the one i entered and return a boolean.

Here is the code i use it always returns false.

```
wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
wifiMgr.startScan();


private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiMgr.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = wifiScanList.get(i).toString();
            }
        }
    }


private boolean doesWifiExist(String string){
        String[] array = string.split(" ");
        String wifi = array[0];

        boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < wifis.length; i++) {
            if(wifis[i].equals(wifi)){
                flag = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Here is the code that i have added and the permissions in the manifest that i use

```
public boolean isInternetPermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("PermissionGranted", "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("PermissionGranted", "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("PermissionGranted", "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }





<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning false probably because the `wifiScanList` is empty. make sure that you request for permission explicitly for newer API's and also make sure wifi is enabled

Comment: can't be, because the for loop in WifiScanReciever would throw a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"`

Also, I believe if you are on, API >= 23 (or Marshmallow, if api is different), you need to call `requestPermission(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})` 
This can be used to request multiple permissions as well, just separate them by commas.

Also one could check permission state by calling
`checkSelfPermission(PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` where PERMISSION equals the permission in which your trying to check.

Comment: i have added the code for asking permission and it works on a api 19 device that i have but it doesn't work on 23 api device that i have.I will add the code in the edit

Comment: It doesn't request on API>=23? my rule of thumb is to place the permission request in the first Activities onCreate, request all needed permission right away, there should be a popup request for wifi.

Comment: i call the function in onCreate

Comment: Wifi is enabled? Debugging these lines give any idication as to the cause of the failure?

Comment: i have the wifi turned on before i think it has something to do with permissions and the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE is a normal permission so you dont have to ask the user for it you only need to have it in the manifest.